# The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application in base controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I'm calling a base method from `ProductController::__construct()`.

`ProductController` is extending `BaseController`.

`BaseController` is extending `Controller`.

Bellow line is also there in `BaseController`

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
```

While executing `$this->getDoctrine()` it is showing me

> Error: Call to a member function has() on null -- The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application.

which can be seen in bellow image.

I'm working with Symfony 2.7

[image: The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application on $this->getDoctrine()]

Comment: Please add your `app/config/config.yml` file

Comment: https://www.i.imgur.com/iKhVvSy.jpg   https://www.i.imgur.com/nQRBqHH.jpg   https://www.i.imgur.com/55kQp4b.jpg  @Mcsky

Answer (score 1):

Symfony's base controller class implements `ContainerAwareInterface` interface, which has a method `setContainer`. When you use this controller regular way via Symfony, it uses this interface to assign the service container under the hood.

When you create your controller instance manually, you have to handle that on your own.

So in short terms, you're missing `$container` field being set with `setContainer` method. That's why you're getting

> Call to a member function has() on **null**

because it's not set yet.

Comment: please help me with this, how can i set Container ? where to set ?

Comment: `$controllerInstance->setContainer($container)` ;-) I don't know in what context you create the controller's instance, therefore it's hard to help you in details. In general you need a service container's instance and pass it to `setContainer` method of the controller right after you create it.

Comment: still didn't work for me. or i'm not getting what to do. can u share sample code which shows initialization of $container. this might be helpful.

Comment: Share the code where you're creating the controller. If you're using whole Symfony Framework and not trying to create your own one basing on Symfony Components, then it shouold already be somewhere ther. Anyway I have no idea why you're trying to create the controller manually. I guess that you're doing something wrong earlier.

Comment: You can also read more about creating container here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html but you probably don't want to create the container manually.